# Porque no guarda el resultado este Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, context

Estoy usando Api Context para guardar el resultado de una petición en el state y luego llevarlo a otros componentes pero no guarda el resultado con la función `setVideos(res.data.items);` como debería ser y no encuentro el problema ya que tampoco tengo un error que me muestre React. No transfiere los datos ni al componente `SearchArea.js` ni al `Results.js`

SearchContext.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

    // Creating Custom Context
    export const SearchContext = createContext();
    
    const SearchProvider = props => {
      const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
      const [error, setError] = useState(null);
      const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
    
      // Calling API
      useEffect(() => {
        const getVideos = async () => {
          const url = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=video&q=${keyword}&part=snippet&maxResults=25&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}`;
    
          try {
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            console.log(res);
    
            if (!res.ok) {
              let err = new Error('Fetch Error');
              err.status = res.status || '00';
              err.statusText = res.statusText || 'There has been a problem';
              throw err;
            }
    
            console.log(res.data.items);
            setVideos(res.data.items);
          } catch (error) {
            // setVideos(null);
            setError(error);
          }
        };
        getVideos();
      }, [keyword]);
    
      return (
        <SearchContext.Provider
          value={{
            videos,
            setKeyword,
            keyword,
            setVideos,
            error,
          }}
        >
          {props.children}
        </SearchContext.Provider>
      );
    };
    
    export default SearchProvider;
```

SearchArea.js

```
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { SearchContext } from '../context/SearchContext';
import Results from './Results';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

const SearchArea = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const { videos, setKeyword, error } = useContext(SearchContext);

  return (
    <>
      <form
        style={{ maxWidth: '50%' }}
        className="mt-5 mx-auto flex flex-col items-center justify-between"
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setLoading(true);
          setKeyword(search);
        }}
      >
        <label
          htmlFor="keyword"
          className="pt-5 font-medium text-black text-center text-xl"
        >
          Search
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="w-full text-center py-2 border mt-3 border-gray-300 rounded-md mb-4"
          id="keyword"
          value={search}
          placeholder="Keywords"
          onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="w-full bg-indigo-600 text-white p-2 rounded-md mb-4">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchArea;
```

Results.js

```
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Video from './Video';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { SearchContext } from '../context/SearchContext';

const Container = styled.div`
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 0.5rem;
`;

const ResultTitle = styled.h3`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1rem 0;
`;

const Results = () => {
  const { keyword, videos } = useContext(SearchContext);

  return (
    <Container>
      <ResultTitle>Results: {keyword}</ResultTitle>
      {videos.map(video => {
        return (
          <Video
            key={video.id.videoId}
            title={video.snippet.title}
            dateAdded={video.snippet.publishedAt}
            channel={video.snippet.channelTitle}
            thumbnails={video.snippet.thumbnails.medium}
            description={video.snippet.description}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Results;
```

Comment: Para ver que lo he entendido bien el resultado de res.data.items visto por console.log es correcto, pero luego en los demás componentes el estado videos del context está vacío.
Que da el console.log(videos) dentro del contexto, ¿también vacío?

Comment: Solo responde el console.log(res) 2 veces cuando inicia la pagína y cuando hago una busqueda bien, pero despues no imprime nada más. Evidentemente hasta ahí está bien el código pero ya revise y no encuentro  errores...

Comment: Esta pasando como array vacío al state videos

Comment: ¿lograste avanzar?, saludos

Comment: El problema fue que estaba pasando los datos al componente App.js donde tenia el Modal.js . Entonces tuve que usar el Context y llevar el componente Modal hacia el componente Video.js